# How to add border to <h1>this text</h1> for outlook

Tags: html, css, email

I am lately working on an email campaign and I want a

## tag

to have a solid border. I used inline CSS and it renders perfect on Gmail, and outlook for web but fails in outlook desktop app.

thanks in advance.

```
<td>
<h1 style="border-bottom: 2px solid red;">this header</h1>
</td>
```

Comment: Remember that markup is pretty much a hint. If the user-agent wants to ignore some markup, or do something different than expected, there is little you can do about it. All user-agents alter the markup to some extent, but Outlook _really_ alters it. Find a way to look at the DOM of the message if possible and see if your markup is even present. It may just ignore it and there might not be a lot you can do.

Comment: This good also be due to outlooks security if it isn't set up to show html https://www.technipages.com/outlook-change-view-html-plain-text

Comment: To my memory Outlook desktop uses Word as its rendering image, so it is limited as it doesn't actually support a lot of HTML niceties. I would suggest looking at litmus for their (massively helpful) browser and client tests to work out how your email will render.

Comment: Thanks, as jdv suggested the markup was changed to a great extent. I followed the way suggested by @scath to inspect markup in outlook. Thanks all :)